# How to get the Sonic Management Console Container logs time stamp using Java?

Tags: java, soa, mq, sonic

Actually I am working in an SOA based Architecture, we are managing our services using the Sonic Management Console.

Every services we will call it as containers .

Manually I can able to login to the Sonic and in the containers section able to see the logs .

I need the help or suggestions how to get those specific container logs last time stamp duration.

Share your ideas,suggestions or examples would be more better .

Answer (score 1):

All the container logs will be stored in sonic install containers folder. If you don't know where this folder is, you can check in "SMC MF Container" -> "Properties" -> "Logging and Auditing" tab.

If you want to read last updated timestamp using Java, you can write a simple Java program to read file attributes. You can also write this as a Sonic ESB service if you want.

I hope this is helpful.